# OpenCV: passing an argument from a C main function to the OpenCV C++ API

Tags: opencv, gcc, g++

I have an application that is written in C, and I would like to use a few OpenCV functions to do some image processing. I see where the C API has been deprecated, so I am currently trying to interface with the C++ API from C. I am running into some compilation issues.

Just to reproduce the example, let's say that I have this C main function in a file `grouping_test_main.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <malloc.h>

extern "C"
{
        #include "opencv_grouping.h"
}
uint8_t **allocate_2D_array(uint32_t SizeY, uint32_t SizeX);
int free_2D_array(uint8_t **image_array, uint32_t SizeY);

int main()
{
        uint32_t SizeY=19;
        uint32_t SizeX=20;
        uint8_t **image_array;
        FILE* fimage_array = fopen("./test_array.txt", "r");
        double threshold_value=128;
        ConnectedComponentsResults results;
        int i;
        int j;

        image_array = allocate_2D_array(SizeY, SizeX);

        for (i=0; i<SizeY; i++)
        {
                for (j=0; j<SizeX; j++)
                {
                        fscanf(fimage_array, "%hhd", &image_array[i][j]);
                }
        }
        fclose(fimage_array);

        treshold_then_group(image_array, SizeY, SizeX, results);
        printf("Number of connected components: %d\n", results.num_components);
        free_2D_array(image_array, SizeY);
}

uint8_t **allocate_2D_array(uint32_t SizeY, uint32_t SizeX)

        /*
         * Allocates memory for a 2D image array.
         */
{
        int i;
        uint8_t **image_array;

        image_array = malloc(SizeY * sizeof(uint8_t *));
        for (i = 0; i < SizeY; i++)
        {
                image_array[i] = malloc(SizeX * sizeof(uint8_t ));
                if(image_array[i] == NULL)
                {
                        fprintf(stderr, "Memory allocation for image_array[%d] failed.\n", i);
                        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                }
        }
        return image_array;
}


int free_2D_array(image_array, SizeY)

        /*
         * Frees memory allocated for 2D image array.
         */

        uint8_t **image_array;
        uint32_t SizeY;
{
        int i;

        for (i = 0; i < SizeY; i++)
        {
                free(image_array[i]);
        }
        return(1);
}
```

`threshold_then_group()` is the C++ function. `test_array.txt` is a text file with a 19X20 array:

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 255 255 255 0 0 0 0 0 0 255 255 255 255 255 0 0 0
0 0 0 255 255 255 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 255 255 255 0 0 0 0
0 0 255 255 255 255 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 255 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 255 255 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 255 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 255 255 255 255 255 0 0 0 0 255 255 255 255 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 255 255 255 255 255 0 0 255 255 255 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 255 255 255 255 255 255 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 255 255 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

`opencv_grouping.h` is the header file where I declare the C++ functions.

```
/* Header file for opencv_grouping.cpp.
 */

#ifndef CONNECTED_COMPONENTS_H
#define CONNECTED_COMPONENTS_H

#include <stdint.h>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

struct ConnectedComponentsResults
{
        int num_components;
        cv::Mat labels;
        cv::Mat stats;
        cv::Mat centroids;
};

void threshold_then_group(uint8_t **image_array, uint32_t SizeY, uint32_t SizeX, double threshold_value, ConnectedComponentsResults &results);

#endif
```

Then, the C++ functions in `opencv_grouping.cpp` are:

```
/* Grouping and centroiding implementation using OpenCV's
 * connectedComponentsWithStats().
 */

#include <stdint.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>

#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include "opencv_grouping.h"

void threshold_then_group(uint8_t **image_array, uint32_t SizeY, uint32_t SizeX, double threshold_value, ConnectedComponentsResults &results)
{
        uint8_t *image_data = new uint8_t[SizeY * SizeX];
        double max_value=255.0;
        int i;
        int j;

        for (i=0; i<SizeY; i++)
        {
                for (j=0; j<SizeX; j++)
                {
                        image_data[i * SizeX + j] = image_array[i][j];
                }
        }

        cv::Mat image(SizeY, SizeX, CV_8U, image_data);

        cv::Mat binary;
        threshold(image, binary, threshold_value, max_value, cv::THRESH_BINARY);

        cv::Mat labels, stats, centroids;

        int num_components = cv::connectedComponentsWithStats(binary, results.labels, results.stats, results.centroids, 8, CV_32S);

        results.num_components = results.stats.rows - 1;

        delete[] image_data;
}
```

I am attempting to compile the code like this:

```
g++ `pkg-config --cflags opencv4` -c opencv_grouping.cpp
gcc `pkg-config --cflags opencv4` -c grouping_test_main.c 
gcc opencv_test.o opencv_grouping.o -lstdc++ `pkg-config --libs opencv4` -o opencv_test2
```

`opencv_grouping.cpp` compiles just fine, but `grouping_test_main.c` fails. This is because `opencv_grouping.h` includes `opencv2/opencv.hpp`, and the error messages indicate that the files included in `opencv.hpp` must be compiled using a C++ compiler. I haven't tried to compile the main function using g++, but even if this somehow works, this isn't really a solution. My actual main function is a lot more complicated than what I've shown here, and it uses a lot of C libraries that I don't think would compile with g++.

Comment: `ConnectedComponentsResults` contains `cv::Mat` instances, so it can't be part of your C-compatible API. `threshold_then_group` needs to only take parameters that C will understand. All the C++ stuff dealing with OpenCV needs to be an implementation detail, and not leak out to the header.

Comment: @DanMašek So I need to convert those `cv::Mat` objects to a form that can be accessed from C?